display property, not working in firefox mozilla
I'm trying to creating a animation, and in this animation I'm setting a display:none and display:block, but not it working in mozilla firefox:( while working good in chrome
tested also with -moz- keyword
@keyframes edit-page-close {
  0% {
    display: block !important;
    top: 15vh;
  }
  100% {
    top: -70vh;
    display: none;
  }
}


Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

I'm sorry. I'm only will to know, why is not working display property in animations css in firefox ?

The display property was until very recently defined as not animatable. There have recently been moves to change this to the discrete animation type. Chrome may have an early implementation, Firefox not quite yet.

I hope it will be fixed soon

Unfortunately, it seems that firefox does not support it, yet. It is a shame, because all other browsers support it! Look for "keyframe animatable" here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#browser_compatibility

Could you please try to use opacity to achieve the same effect. Also display can't be animated with CSS because display is not animated property.


@keyframes edit-page-close {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    top: 15vh;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: -70vh;
  }
}



Please let me know if this helps.

thank you, but I'm forgot adding this  case to question, that I'm not used display for animated !. rather I'm setting it (display) for close edit page after top: -70vh , by a button click, page closed and it adding this ClassName .admin-edit-page-close {animation-duration: 0.5s; animation-name: edit-page-close; animation-fill-mode: forwards; position: fixed; } that in this styles, I'm setting this animation that after  top: -70vh; edit page element none display . your offer also not show it but also existed element .

What you mean by immobility is that absolutely display in animations not working ?. If so, then I was thinking wrong about the functionality of animatios and transitions

Since very recently, display is animated (discrete but still)
